# issue with stage.setViewport

Tags: android, libgdx

This might be the stupid question, however, i cant find answer anywhere. I followed the this [post](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) on scaling the stage.

```
 public void resize (int width, int height) {

    Vector2 size = Scaling.fit.apply(800, 480, width, height);
    int viewportX = (int)(width - size.x) / 2;
    int viewportY = (int)(height - size.y) / 2;
    int viewportWidth = (int)size.x;
    int viewportHeight = (int)size.y;
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(viewportX, viewportY, viewportWidth, viewportHeight);
    stage.setViewport(800, 480, true, viewportX, viewportY, viewportWidth, viewportHeight);
}
```

However, Eclipse display the following error message. Any idea? libgdx version 0.9.8.
"The method setViewport(float, float, boolean) in the type Stage is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, boolean, int, int, int, int)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mystage = new Stage(scrw, scrh, false);
```

scrw is viewport's width,

scrh is view port's height.

this worked for mee smoothlyy..

Answer (score 0):

API was changed and here is the new code for that:

```
Stage stage;
public void create() {
    stage = new Stage(
        new StretchViewport( 
            Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight() 
        )
    );
}
```